# Possible embedded database engines to use in an application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Are there any alternative to SQLite to use as embedded database engine?

Comment: Why?  SQLite [and Core Data] are amazingly scalable and extremely well supported.  If you need client/server, obviously, you need to look elsewhere, but for a pure embedded, local, role it is hard to beat in all but uncommon circumstances.

Comment: I tested the code for an application I am writing and that uses SQLite, and I found out that it is getting too slow, after adding X rows to the database. I could possibly still using SQLite, but I wanted to know if there are any alternatives to SQLite / Core Data.

Comment: Did you do any profiling or analysis to determine why it was slow? SQLite is very efficient; if something was getting progressively slower, perhaps that represents a bug in your code to investigate.

A common case of this is importing data via an "add if absent" method that does a fetch/query to see if some data already exists and only inserts if it doesn't. This is going to be inefficient no matter what database you use.

Comment: @Chris Hanson: That is what I thought too; the co-maintainer of the application suggested to verify the performance with another database.
I am not in favor of adopting a different database engine, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  [This page](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/database) shows a couple non-SQLite frameworks (besides Core Data):

- [BaseTen Framework](http://basetenframework.org/)
- [MySQL-Cocoa](http://mysql-cocoa.sourceforge.net/)
- [ODBCKit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/odbckit/)

I have no idea how awesome these projects are, so YMMV.

If you're looking to avoid external dependencies (ie, not shipping a framework with your app), then you're stuck with SQLite or CoreData.  CoreData can use XML as its format, but it has some disadvantages.  SQLite is definitely the most recommended CoreData backend.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted it, but I don't think any of your suggestions are *embedded* database engines.

Comment: @JWWalker if you define "embedded" as "shippable with the application", they are, since they're for frameworks (and the question is tagged `osx`)

Comment: I meant to ask about an embedded database engine without external dependencies, but I didn't made that explicit. I don't see anything wrong in the interpretation given by Dave DeLong. About the links he gave, all the three frameworks are reported to be for Cocoa; even if I understand that ODBC was born for Windows, I expressly excluded that.

Comment: May you modify the text of your answer (it's enough you add a new line)? I made something wrong, and now Stack Overflow tells me that I voted 28 minutes ago, and my vote is locked. I think it must be I clicked twice, annulling the vote I made (in fact, I don't see the orange arrow).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of alternatives to `SQLite` if you want to have an embedded database engine, such as:

- [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) [[1]](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ufb-cs-embedded.html)
- [BerkleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html)
- [MySQL Embedded Server](http://www.mysql.com/oem/)

Be sure to also check the licensing terms.

**EDIT:**

Firebird is licenced under a derivative `MPL` licence, so it can be used in `closed-source` applications (see [FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq11/)). The other two are `dual-licenced` so you need to pay if you are going to use them in commercial applications.